# Passing values between different applications in ExtJS 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

Currently I am working on an project where ExtJS 4.2 is used for the UI. So suppose I have a standalone project X (a  .war application) deployed in server(tomcat) . So if I am creating another standalone project Y(another .war application) and deploy it to server(different tomcat) , is there any way to pass values from one view of UI of Project X to one view of UI of Project Y and vice versa.

Currently the projects works on mvc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass messages (values) on client side(UI). Moreover, even somehow you can manage to do it, it is very bad practice.

1) You can use HTTP / JSON service calls between applications and using web sockets/ polling get message with other application's UI.

ie. X app  calls Y apps web service and Y pushes notification to UI with websockets/ polling.

2) Another way in UI Y calls X web service (HTTP/JSON or SOAP ) and gets messages.